PirmeVue Carousel css not loaded
I want to use PrimeVue's Carousel under VueJs. I can see that the carousel is working, but the styles are not applied (compared to sample on the website). If anyone could help me, or pint me in the right direction.
//main.js
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import ConfirmationService from 'primevue/confirmationservice'
import DialogService from 'primevue/dialogservice'
import ToastService from 'primevue/toastservice';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes';
import App from './App.vue';
import appTheme from './theme';
import AppState from './appState.js';

import './style.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

const app = createApp(App)
            .use(router)
            .use(PrimeVue, {
              theme: {
                preset: appTheme,
                options: {
                  cssLayer: {
                    name: 'primevue',
                    order: 'tailwind-base, primevue, tailwind-utilities'
                  },
                  prefix: 'p',
                  darkModeSelector: 'none',
                  cssLayer: false,
                }
              }
            });

app.use(AppState);
app.use(ConfirmationService);
app.use(ToastService);
app.use(DialogService);

app.mount('#app')

//tailwind.config.js
import { primeui } from 'tailwindcss-primeui'
import { forms } from 'tailwindcss-forms';
export default {
    content: [
        './index.html',
        './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
    ],
    darkMode: ['selector', '[class="p-dark"]'],
    plugins: [primeui, forms]
};


//postcss.config.js

export const plugins = {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
};

//added the following lines to style.css
@layer tailwind-base, primevue, tailwind-utilities;

@layer tailwind-base {
    @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
}

// appTheme.js
import Material from '@primevue/themes/material';
import { definePreset } from '@primevue/themes';

const appTheme = definePreset(Material, {
    primitive: {
        borderRadius: {
            none: "0",
            xs: "2px",
            sm: "4px",
            md: "6px",
            lg: "8px",
            xl: "12px"
        },
        emerald: {
            50: "#E8F6F1",
            100: "#C5EBE1",
            200: "#9EDFCF",
            300: "#76D3BD",
            400: "#58C9AF",
            500: "#3BBFA1",
            600: "#35AF94",
            700: "#2D9B83",
            800: "#268873",
            900: "#1A6657",
            950: "#0d3329"
        },
        green: {
            50: "#E8F5E9",
            100: "#C8E6C9",
            200: "#A5D6A7",
            300: "#81C784",
            400: "#66BB6A",
            500: "#4CAF50",
            600: "#43A047",
            700: "#388E3C",
            800: "#2E7D32",
            900: "#1B5E20",
            950: "#0e2f10"
        },
        lime: {
            50: "#F9FBE7",
            100: "#F0F4C3",
            200: "#E6EE9C",
            300: "#DCE775",
            400: "#D4E157",
            500: "#CDDC39",
            600: "#C0CA33",
            700: "#AFB42B",
            800: "#9E9D24",
            900: "#827717",
            950: "#413c0c"
        },
        red: {
            50: "#FFEBEE",
            100: "#FFCDD2",
            200: "#EF9A9A",
            300: "#E57373",
            400: "#EF5350",
            500: "#F44336",
            600: "#E53935",
            700: "#D32F2F",
            800: "#C62828",
            900: "#B71C1C",
            950: "#5c0e0e"
        },
        orange: {
            50: "#FFF3E0",
            100: "#FFE0B2",
            200: "#FFCC80",
            300: "#FFB74D",
            400: "#FFA726",
            500: "#FF9800",
            600: "#FB8C00",
            700: "#F57C00",
            800: "#EF6C00",
            900: "#E65100",
            950: "#732900"
        },
        amber: {
            50: "#FFF8E1",
            100: "#FFECB3",
            200: "#FFE082",
            300: "#FFD54F",
            400: "#FFCA28",
            500: "#FFC107",
            600: "#FFB300",
            700: "#FFA000",
            800: "#FF8F00",
            900: "#FF6F00",
            950: "#803800"
        },
        yellow: {
            50: "#FFFDE7",
            100: "#FFF9C4",
            200: "#FFF59D",
            300: "#FFF176",
            400: "#FFEE58",
            500: "#FFEB3B",
            600: "#FDD835",
            700: "#FBC02D",
            800: "#F9A825",
            900: "#F57F17",
            950: "#7b400c"
        },
        teal: {
            50: "#E0F2F1",
            100: "#B2DFDB",
            200: "#80CBC4",
            300: "#4DB6AC",
            400: "#26A69A",
            500: "#009688",
            600: "#00897B",
            700: "#00796B",
            800: "#00695C",
            900: "#004D40",
            950: "#002720"
        },
        cyan: {
            50: "#E0F7FA",
            100: "#B2EBF2",
            200: "#80DEEA",
            300: "#4DD0E1",
            400: "#26C6DA",
            500: "#00BCD4",
            600: "#00ACC1",
            700: "#0097A7",
            800: "#00838F",
            900: "#006064",
            950: "#003032"
        },
        sky: {
            50: "#E1F5FE",
            100: "#B3E5FC",
            200: "#81D4FA",
            300: "#4FC3F7",
            400: "#29B6F6",
            500: "#03A9F4",
            600: "#039BE5",
            700: "#0288D1",
            800: "#0277BD",
            900: "#01579B",
            950: "#012c4e"
        },
        blue: {
            50: "#E3F2FD",
            100: "#BBDEFB",
            200: "#90CAF9",
            300: "#64B5F6",
            400: "#42A5F5",
            500: "#2196F3",
            600: "#1E88E5",
            700: "#1976D2",
            800: "#1565C0",
            900: "#0D47A1",
            950: "#072451"
        },
        indigo: {
            50: "#E8EAF6",
            100: "#C5CAE9",
            200: "#9FA8DA",
            300: "#7986CB",
            400: "#5C6BC0",
            500: "#3F51B5",
            600: "#3949AB",
            700: "#303F9F",
            800: "#283593",
            900: "#1A237E",
            950: "#0d123f"
        },
        violet: {
            50: "#EDE7F6",
            100: "#D1C4E9",
            200: "#B39DDB",
            300: "#9575CD",
            400: "#7E57C2",
            500: "#673AB7",
            600: "#5E35B1",
            700: "#512DA8",
            800: "#4527A0",
            900: "#311B92",
            950: "#190e49"
        },
        purple: {
            50: "#fdf5f9",
            100: "#f4cee1",
            200: "#eba8c9",
            300: "#e281b1",
            400: "#da5b99",
            500: "#d13481",
            600: "#b22c6e",
            700: "#92245a",
            800: "#731d47",
            900: "#541534",
            950: "#340d20"
        },
        fuchsia: {
            50: "#FDE6F3",
            100: "#FBC1E3",
            200: "#F897D1",
            300: "#F56DBF",
            400: "#F34DB2",
            500: "#F12DA5",
            600: "#E0289D",
            700: "#CC2392",
            800: "#B81E88",
            900: "#951777",
            950: "#4b0c3c"
        },
        pink: {
            50: "#FCE4EC",
            100: "#F8BBD0",
            200: "#F48FB1",
            300: "#F06292",
            400: "#EC407A",
            500: "#E91E63",
            600: "#D81B60",
            700: "#C2185B",
            800: "#AD1457",
            900: "#880E4F",
            950: "#440728"
        },
        rose: {
            50: "#FFF0F0",
            100: "#FFD9D9",
            200: "#FFC0C0",
            300: "#FFA7A7",
            400: "#FF8E8E",
            500: "#FF7575",
            600: "#FF5252",
            700: "#FF3838",
            800: "#F71C1C",
            900: "#D50000",
            950: "#3E0000"
        },
        slate: {
            50: "#f8fafc",
            100: "#f1f5f9",
            200: "#e2e8f0",
            300: "#cbd5e1",
            400: "#94a3b8",
            500: "#64748b",
            600: "#475569",
            700: "#334155",
            800: "#1e293b",
            900: "#0f172a",
            950: "#020617"
        },
        gray: {
            50: "#f9fafb",
            100: "#f3f4f6",
            200: "#e5e7eb",
            300: "#d1d5db",
            400: "#9ca3af",
            500: "#6b7280",
            600: "#4b5563",
            700: "#374151",
            800: "#1f2937",
            900: "#111827",
            950: "#030712"
        },
        zinc: {
            50: "#fafafa",
            100: "#f4f4f5",
            200: "#e4e4e7",
            300: "#d4d4d8",
            400: "#a1a1aa",
            500: "#71717a",
            600: "#52525b",
            700: "#3f3f46",
            800: "#27272a",
            900: "#18181b",
            950: "#09090b"
        },
        neutral: {
            50: "#fafafa",
            100: "#f5f5f5",
            200: "#e5e5e5",
            300: "#d4d4d4",
            400: "#a3a3a3",
            500: "#737373",
            600: "#525252",
            700: "#404040",
            800: "#262626",
            900: "#171717",
            950: "#0a0a0a"
        },
        stone: {
            50: "#fafaf9",
            100: "#f5f5f4",
            200: "#e7e5e4",
            300: "#d6d3d1",
            400: "#a8a29e",
            500: "#78716c",
            600: "#57534e",
            700: "#44403c",
            800: "#292524",
            900: "#1c1917",
            950: "#0c0a09"
        }
    },
    semantic: {
        transitionDuration: "0.2s",
        focusRing: {
            width: "0",
            style: "none",
            color: "unset",
            offset: "0"
        },
        disabledOpacity: "0.38",
        iconSize: "1rem",
        anchorGutter: "0",
        primary: {
            50: "#fdf5f9",
            100: "#f4cee1",
            200: "#eba8c9",
            300: "#e281b1",
            400: "#da5b99",
            500: "#d13481",
            600: "#b22c6e",
            700: "#92245a",
            800: "#731d47",
            900: "#541534",
            950: "#340d20"
        },
        secondary: {
            50: "#f9f4f9",
            100: "#e1c9e1",
            200: "#c99eca",
            300: "#b274b2",
            400: "#9a499b",
            500: "#821e83",
            600: "#6f1a6f",
            700: "#5b155c",
            800: "#481148",
            900: "#340c34",
            950: "#210821"
        },
        formField: {
            paddingX: "0.75rem",
            paddingY: "0.75rem",
            sm: {
                fontSize: "0.875rem",
                paddingX: "0.625rem",
                paddingY: "0.625rem"
            },
            lg: {
                fontSize: "1.125rem",
                paddingX: "0.825rem",
                paddingY: "0.825rem"
            },
            borderRadius: "{border.radius.sm}",
            focusRing: {
                width: "2px",
                style: "solid",
                color: "{primary.color}",
                offset: "-2px",
                shadow: "none"
            },
            transitionDuration: "{transition.duration}"
        },
        list: {
            padding: "0.5rem 0",
            gap: "0",
            header: {
                padding: "0.75rem 1rem"
            },
            option: {
                padding: "0.75rem 1rem",
                borderRadius: "{border.radius.none}"
            },
            optionGroup: {
                padding: "0.75rem 1rem",
                fontWeight: "700"
            }
        },
        content: {
            borderRadius: "{border.radius.sm}"
        },
        mask: {
            transitionDuration: "0.15s"
        },
        navigation: {
            list: {
                padding: "0.5rem 0",
                gap: "0"
            },
            item: {
                padding: "0.75rem 1rem",
                borderRadius: "{border.radius.none}",
                gap: "0.5rem"
            },
            submenuLabel: {
                padding: "0.75rem 1rem",
                fontWeight: "700"
            },
            submenuIcon: {
                size: "0.875rem"
            }
        },
        overlay: {
            select: {
                borderRadius: "{border.radius.sm}",
                shadow: "0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
            },
            popover: {
                borderRadius: "{border.radius.sm}",
                padding: "1rem",
                shadow: "0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
            },
            modal: {
                borderRadius: "{border.radius.sm}",
                padding: "1.5rem",
                shadow: "0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
            },
            navigation: {
                shadow: "0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
            }
        },
        colorScheme: {
            light: {
                focusRing: {
                    shadow: "0 0 1px 4px {surface.200}"
                },
                surface: {
                    0: "#ffffff",
                    50: "#f8fafc",
                    100: "#f1f5f9",
                    200: "#e2e8f0",
                    300: "#cbd5e1",
                    400: "#94a3b8",
                    500: "#64748b",
                    600: "#475569",
                    700: "#334155",
                    800: "#1e293b",
                    900: "#0f172a",
                    950: "#020617"
                },
                primary: {
                    color: "{primary.500}",
                    contrastColor: "#ffffff",
                    hoverColor: "{primary.400}",
                    activeColor: "{primary.300}"
                },
                highlight: {
                    background: "color-mix(in srgb, {primary.color}, transparent 88%)",
                    focusBackground: "color-mix(in srgb, {primary.color}, transparent 76%)",
                    color: "{primary.700}",
                    focusColor: "{primary.800}"
                },
                mask: {
                    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.32)",
                    color: "{surface.200}"
                },
                formField: {
                    background: "{surface.0}",
                    disabledBackground: "{surface.300}",
                    filledBackground: "{surface.100}",
                    filledHoverBackground: "{surface.200}",
                    filledFocusBackground: "{surface.100}",
                    borderColor: "{surface.400}",
                    hoverBorderColor: "{surface.900}",
                    focusBorderColor: "{primary.color}",
                    invalidBorderColor: "{red.800}",
                    color: "{surface.900}",
                    disabledColor: "{surface.600}",
                    placeholderColor: "{surface.600}",
                    invalidPlaceholderColor: "{red.800}",
                    floatLabelColor: "{surface.600}",
                    floatLabelFocusColor: "{primary.600}",
                    floatLabelActiveColor: "{surface.600}",
                    floatLabelInvalidColor: "{form.field.invalid.placeholder.color}",
                    iconColor: "{surface.600}",
                    shadow: "none"
                },
                text: {
                    color: "{surface.900}",
                    hoverColor: "{surface.900}",
                    mutedColor: "{surface.600}",
                    hoverMutedColor: "{surface.600}"
                },
                content: {
                    background: "{surface.0}",
                    hoverBackground: "{surface.100}",
                    borderColor: "{surface.300}",
                    color: "{text.color}",
                    hoverColor: "{text.hover.color}"
                },
                overlay: {
                    select: {
                        background: "{surface.0}",
                        borderColor: "{surface.0}",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    },
                    popover: {
                        background: "{surface.0}",
                        borderColor: "{surface.0}",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    },
                    modal: {
                        background: "{surface.0}",
                        borderColor: "{surface.0}",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    }
                },
                list: {
                    option: {
                        focusBackground: "{surface.100}",
                        selectedBackground: "{highlight.background}",
                        selectedFocusBackground: "{highlight.focus.background}",
                        color: "{text.color}",
                        focusColor: "{text.hover.color}",
                        selectedColor: "{highlight.color}",
                        selectedFocusColor: "{highlight.focus.color}",
                        icon: {
                            color: "{surface.600}",
                            focusColor: "{surface.600}"
                        }
                    },
                    optionGroup: {
                        background: "transparent",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    }
                },
                navigation: {
                    item: {
                        focusBackground: "{surface.100}",
                        activeBackground: "{surface.200}",
                        color: "{text.color}",
                        focusColor: "{text.hover.color}",
                        activeColor: "{text.hover.color}",
                        icon: {
                            color: "{surface.600}",
                            focusColor: "{surface.600}",
                            activeColor: "{surface.600}"
                        }
                    },
                    submenuLabel: {
                        background: "transparent",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    },
                    submenuIcon: {
                        color: "{surface.600}",
                        focusColor: "{surface.600}",
                        activeColor: "{surface.600}"
                    }
                }
            },
            dark: {
                focusRing: {
                    shadow: "0 0 1px 4px {surface.700}"
                },
                surface: {
                    0: "#ffffff",
                    50: "#fafafa",
                    100: "#f4f4f5",
                    200: "#e4e4e7",
                    300: "#d4d4d8",
                    400: "#a1a1aa",
                    500: "#71717a",
                    600: "#52525b",
                    700: "#3f3f46",
                    800: "#27272a",
                    900: "#18181b",
                    950: "#09090b"
                },
                primary: {
                    color: "{primary.400}",
                    contrastColor: "{surface.900}",
                    hoverColor: "{primary.300}",
                    activeColor: "{primary.200}"
                },
                highlight: {
                    background: "color-mix(in srgb, {primary.400}, transparent 84%)",
                    focusBackground: "color-mix(in srgb, {primary.400}, transparent 76%)",
                    color: "rgba(255,255,255,.87)",
                    focusColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.87)"
                },
                mask: {
                    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
                    color: "{surface.200}"
                },
                formField: {
                    background: "{surface.950}",
                    disabledBackground: "{surface.700}",
                    filledBackground: "{surface.800}",
                    filledHoverBackground: "{surface.700}",
                    filledFocusBackground: "{surface.800}",
                    borderColor: "{surface.600}",
                    hoverBorderColor: "{surface.400}",
                    focusBorderColor: "{primary.color}",
                    invalidBorderColor: "{red.300}",
                    color: "{surface.0}",
                    disabledColor: "{surface.400}",
                    placeholderColor: "{surface.400}",
                    invalidPlaceholderColor: "{red.300}",
                    floatLabelColor: "{surface.400}",
                    floatLabelFocusColor: "{primary.color}",
                    floatLabelActiveColor: "{surface.400}",
                    floatLabelInvalidColor: "{form.field.invalid.placeholder.color}",
                    iconColor: "{surface.400}",
                    shadow: "none"
                },
                text: {
                    color: "{surface.0}",
                    hoverColor: "{surface.0}",
                    mutedColor: "{surface.400}",
                    hoverMutedColor: "{surface.400}"
                },
                content: {
                    background: "{surface.900}",
                    hoverBackground: "{surface.800}",
                    borderColor: "{surface.700}",
                    color: "{text.color}",
                    hoverColor: "{text.hover.color}"
                },
                overlay: {
                    select: {
                        background: "{surface.900}",
                        borderColor: "{surface.900}",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    },
                    popover: {
                        background: "{surface.900}",
                        borderColor: "{surface.900}",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    },
                    modal: {
                        background: "{surface.900}",
                        borderColor: "{surface.900}",
                        color: "{text.color}"
                    }
                },
                list: {
                    option: {
                        focusBackground: "{surface.800}",
                        selectedBackground: "{highlight.background}",
                        selectedFocusBackground: "{highlight.focus.background}",
                        color: "{text.color}",
                        focusColor: "{text.hover.color}",
                        selectedColor: "{highlight.color}",
                        selectedFocusColor: "{highlight.focus.color}",
                        icon: {
                            color: "{surface.400}",
                            focusColor: "{surface.400}"
                        }
                    },
                    optionGroup: {
                        background: "transparent",
                        color: "{text.muted.color}"
                    }
                },
                navigation: {
                    item: {
                        focusBackground: "{surface.800}",
                        activeBackground: "{surface.700}",
                        color: "{text.color}",
                        focusColor: "{text.hover.color}",
                        activeColor: "{text.hover.color}",
                        icon: {
                            color: "{surface.400}",
                            focusColor: "{surface.400}",
                            activeColor: "{surface.400}"
                        }
                    },
                    submenuLabel: {
                        background: "transparent",
                        color: "{text.muted.color}"
                    },
                    submenuIcon: {
                        color: "{surface.400}",
                        focusColor: "{surface.400}",
                        activeColor: "{surface.400}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    components: {
    }
});

export default appTheme;

thnx

PrimeVue styling comes from theme: preset option in main.js.  Yours is set to some imported value which may or may not be correct. We'd need more information about what appTheme is. According to the docs, "Aura, Material, Lara and Nora are the available built-in options" for preset themes. You can try importing one of those preset themes and verify if it works.

I tried to reproduce to the best of my ability using your code (and with code from the documentation): stackblitz demo, and was not able to reproduce the issue.  Do you have any console errors or warnings? Try reproducing your issue in your own stackblitz or other online sandbox and add it to the question.

No, I do not have any error. At the and I cloned the stackblitz demo and put my code in it and it started working.

There's something unique to your project configuration then that is the root cause.  Maybe a package or other stylesheet conflict somewhere.  If the problem can not be reproduced, then an answer here can't be provided. You'll need to do more debugging, or provide github repo of your project that others can debug.
